# Does pressure affect rate constant?

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetics

I would like to know if pressure affects rate constant.

Suppose pressure affects the rate constant. Does it depend on partial pressure (like: if I add an inert gas to the system), or only increasing the pressure of at least one of the reagents?

Comment: In solution there is a pressure dependence via the transition state as $d\ln(k)/dP=-\Delta V^*/RT$, where $\Delta V^*$ is the difference in molar volume between transition state and reactants. Typically thousands of bar are needed and the volume change is $\approx 5 \to 15$ mL/mole so small. In peroxide radical decomposition , pressure is observed to affect reaction via packing in solvent cage.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, pressure affects just the reaction rate, not the rate constant, like for $\ce{A + B -> C}$:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}C}{d\mathrm{t}} = k_1 \cdot p_\mathrm{A} \cdot p_\mathrm{B}$$

In case the are some non-linear effects and the reaction rate does follow the simple equation like above, with integer/half-integer exponents, there are possible several formal aproaches:

Formulating reaction rate function like:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}C}{d\mathrm{t}} = k_2 \cdot f(p_\mathrm{A}, p_\mathrm{B})$$

or, if deviation is just slight, it could be written as:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}C}{d\mathrm{t}} = k_3(p_\mathrm{A}, p_\mathrm{B}) \cdot p_\mathrm{A} \cdot p_\mathrm{B},$$

or there can be derived different $k_1$ values optimal for particular partial pressure ranges.

Comment: Thank for your replay
So to confirm, the rate constant may alter slightly in some reactions with having different partial pressures.
Aslo I would like to be 100% sure: concentrations cant affect the rate constant

Comment: I would rather say the rate constant at given temperature does not change, unless the used reaction rate equation is just an approximation of the true reaction rate equation .

Comment: I once had a question that asked which the rate constant was NOT dependent on: Pressure, Temperature, catalyst, concentrations.
I know rate constant was dependent on temperature, catalyst. I believe that rate constant did not depend on concentration, so I thought that concentration should be the answer but then that will mean rate constant pressure is dependent

Comment: Well, you can express gas composition in both equivalent ways, in partial pressures or in molar concentrations. Rate constants cannot be dependent on one set of the quantities and independent on the other.